# how to get back to fragment from activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have four fragments in an Activity C. they are behaving as tabs. I have to go from a fragment to a new Activity X. Now i want to come back to fragment from Activity X to fragment.

here is my main activity

'public class MainInterface extends ActionBarActivity {

```
ViewPager pager;
PagerTabStrip tab_strp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_interface);
    MainPagerAdapter mapager = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.setAdapter(mapager);
    tab_strp = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tab_strip);
    //tab_strp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    //tab_strp.setTextSize(14,14);
     //tab_strp.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#2196f3")));
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Instructor");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}
'

here is activity
'public class Discussions extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
ImageButton post;
TextView dTitle;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.discussions,container,false);
    post=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.ibDisc);
    post.setOnClickListener(this);

    dTitle=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvDiscTitle);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),PostDiscussion.class);
    startActivity(in);

}
```

}'

Comment: Provide some code: How are you starting your Activity, how do you get back? What have you tried?

Comment: you have to go to the Activity X from Activity C (which has four Fragments), right?

Comment: no i have to go one of the fragment in activity C

Answer (score 1):

[image]Save the name of your fragment in sharedPreferences before navigating to new activity and onBackpressed of that new activity or when you want to come back to same fragment get the name from SharedPreferences and add that particular fragment to the earlier activity